# Kendo Grid. Razor Mode. Column Sorting

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI Grid in my current project. I found out that Sorting doesn't work if column has Template.
In following solution fix only for javascript grid realization:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/row-template-sorting.aspx

How to achive sorting in Razor mode?

Example of column with template:
     columns.Bound(e => e.OrderNumber).Template(e => @Html.ActionLink(e.OrderNumber.ToString(), "Test", "Test"));

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Template for the column and/or using a RowTemplate should not affect the sorting support.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/IXONeRaN/2/edit) is an example via JavaScript (Razor outputs JavaScript at the end and should make no difference)

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    sortable:true,
    rowTemplate:"foo #= ProductID#",
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field:"ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
        { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "100px" },
        { field: "Discontinued", width: "100px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "160px" }],
    editable: "popup"
});
```

Comment: You are right. Template doesn't break Sorting. In my case HeaderTemplate did it.I found answer here:http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/how-to-add-custom-header-with-sort-graphics.aspx. Still thanks for your help and time.